# Where OpenBSD stores information about pseudo interfaces

Tags: vlan, openbsd

On my OpenBSD machine i have several pseudo interfaces for vlan that looks like

```
vlan3: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        lladdr 00:04:e2:c5:02:2b
        vlan: 3 parent interface: sk0
        groups: vlan 
        inet6 fe80::204:e2ff:fec5:22b%vlan3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa
        inet 10.0.172.253 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.172.255
```

These interfaces remained from previous sysadmin.

There are no /etc/hostname. files for it, so i'm just wondering where does it come from?

Comment: Did you check your `/etc/rc.conf` file.

Comment: @Cocoabean Yes, i did. Nothing related.

Comment: It's possible that the previous admin created them on the fly with commands and never set them to survive reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of setting up vlan's is using /etc/hostname.vlan1 (replacing 1 with whatever number of course) but technically, I suppose the previous admin could have written it into the  /etc/netstart file which itself, looks for /etc/hostname.$if.  I doubt though anyone would go and put it in there.

I know it's a longshot, but is it at all possible that the machine simply hasn't been rebooted, and these vlans were created on the command line, and there never *was* anything setup to ensure they'd be recreated on reboot?